# What uses the most processing power. Comparing two values, or setting one value equal to another?

Tags: compare, processing, operator-keyword

This is a question I haven't been able to find an answer to.

The reason for asking is that in one of my projects, I am running through several million values 60 times a second, and changing them. I want to know if it would be more efficient to compare it with the value I am changing it to first, to see if it already has that value.

My immediate thought is no. "value = otherValue" and "if (value == otherValue)" I would expect to require the same amount of power to process, since they both consist of one single operation. I could be wrong though. Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: Did you try profiling both options?

Comment: How do you make it both single operation? the first is a single operation (mv value1, value2) but the if is not (cmp value1, value2 / je equals). An if can't be seen as simply evaluating the expression, it is also the jump (or jumps) it entails

Comment: The processing tag should only be used for the Processing language, as a general processing tag would be pretty meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think the hardware architecture is important here as well (what processor works here)

The "If" version requires you to branch after the if according to results. (most processor today use branch prediction) but in the first option it's a single operation and in the "if" version you compare (lets assume it's one operation - you need to fetch both vars to register and cmp them, and then if they different you need to set and store).

So in average the "if" method should cost MORE.

One way to find the correct answer would be to test it on a few million different variables and value and compare the results.

Comment: Note also that the bottleneck in either case is likely to be memory bandwidth.

Comment: fetch might cost a lot here... but I guess you will have to access the memory anyway in both cases, I guess the source of this question is where writing cost more than reading and comparing...

Comment: value = othervalue is just storing a value in memory - one mv operation unless the value to store goes over the processors limites (store a 64bit value using a 32bit processor would take 2 mv operations - or more if it does any error checking). An if on the other side would always be at least two operation - a cmp and a jump (je, jne, jgt, jlt, jge, jle). Given this, unless there's some if statement optimization i don't know about, the if would weight in more on the processor - not to mention the memory jump time (moving to a new place in the code)